# Why I have to command “source virtualenvwrapper.sh” every time I open a new Terminal for use workon?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I want to use `virtualenvwrapper`. But when I close a terminal then open a new one, I have to command "source `virtualenvwrapper.sh`" again then I can use `workon`.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a new terminal, a NEW `bash` process is started. See `man bash` (or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html ), the "`INVOCATION`" section.

Inspect `virtualenvwrapper.sh`, and see if it can be merged with your current startup file.

Or, if your `$HOME` directory is clean enough, you could type ". v<kbd>Tab</kbd>", instead of `source virtualenvwrapper.sh`.